# Simple Form drop down menu, string selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I use simple form with my rails 4 app.

I have a show page in my app with this identifier for location:

```
<div class="datasubtextq">Location:
        <span class="datasubtexta">
          <% if @project.scope.try(:participant).try(:location_specific) == true %>
            <%= render @project.scope.try(:participant).try(:location) %>
          <% else %>
            <%= render :text => "Remote participation sought" %>
          <% end %>
        </span>
  </div>
```

In my form, I ask users to select a location, as follows:

```
                    <%= par.input :location, label: 'Where will participants take part in this project?', label_html: {class: 'response-project'}, collection: [ "Brisbane", "Melbourne", "Sydney" ], prompt: "Choose one" %>
```

When I test this, I get the following error:

```
The partial name (Brisbane) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with a lowercase letter or underscore, and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and underscores.
```

How do I ask for the show form to reflect the location selection made in the form?

Thank you

Comment: Based on the error, you are trying to render 'Brisbane'  that is the result of `try(: location)`, do you have a partial called `Brisbane`? I guess you want to  render your form, right? So change `render @project....` for something like `render 'your_form'`

Comment: No  - I don't have a partial called Brisbane. Brisbane is one of the choices in the collection of options in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error you get, you can see the issue is related to try to render a partial that does not exists and is ok, to fix the issue change

```
<%= render @project.scope.try(:participant).try(:location) %>
```

with

```
<%= @project.scope.try(:participant).try(:location) %>
```